# Bootstrap popover not firing after a first popover is initiated

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have taken a small look around here and I can see this is a problem that does occur, but I am still not sure of the solution:

I have a JS Bin illustrating this issue:
https://jsbin.com/toqirix/edit?html,js,output

To replicate the issue:

1. Put "0" into the first input.
2. Put "2" into both the next inputs (or any number that is identical).
3. Click the button and the result should be a popover that says "You have chosen 0, this needs to be non-zero"
4. Change the "0" in `input-a` to any non-zero number.
5. Click the button again - now nothing happens.

What is meant to happen is the next "if" statement should be called. This will tell you that b and c should not be the same.

So, why is this not happening?

How can I make it so that after the button is clicked and the popup is removed that the next popup will come up if the button is clicked again?

The JS (located at JSBin)

**Snippet**

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", calc);

function calc() {
  let a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);
  let b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b").value);
  let c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c").value);
  let output = document.getElementById("output");

  if (a === 0) {
    $(this).popover({
      placement: "bottom",
      content: '<textarea class="popover-textarea"></textarea>',
      template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div>' +
        '<div class="row"><div class="col-3 my-auto">' +
        '</div><div class="popover-content col-9">You have chosen 0, this needs to be non-zero' +
        "</div></div>",
    });
    $(this).popover("show");
    $(this).click(function() {
      $(this).popover("hide");
    });
    return false;
  } else if (b === c) {
    $(this).popover({
      placement: "bottom",
      content: '<textarea class="popover-textarea"></textarea>',
      template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div>' +
        '<div class="row"><div class="col-3 my-auto">' +
        '</div><div class="popover-content col-9">You have chosen b and c to be the same, they need to be different' +
        "</div></div>",
    });
    $(this).popover("show");
    $(this).click(function() {
      $(this).popover("hide");
    });
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" id="a">
  <input type="number" id="b">
  <input type="number" id="c">
  <button type="button" id="submit">Hit me</button>
</form>
<p id="output"></p>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your code is using Bootstrap 4 JavaScript with Bootstrap 5 css. Mixing versions can have unpredictable results.

Comment: True... but the same outcome occurs locally where I am using Bootstrap 4. But I will change that. Thanks.

Comment: I've adjusted it now to 4.5.2. I had all sorts of errors with Bootstrap 5 locally. I couldn't get dropdowns to work in the navbar even when I changed all the data-bs-* as instructed. So I gave up and went back to 4.3.1 distributed.

Comment: There are multiple mistakes in your code. The problem has nothing to do with Bootstrap.

Comment: @Yogi - that's good then, it is fixable. Unfortunately, I can't see the issues - can you help me out there? I a bit too fresh to see this.

Comment: I tried using `$(this).popover("dispose");` before each of the `$(this).popover` and remove all the 
```$(this).click(function() {
      $(this).popover("hide");
    });
```, the effect you want seems to be realised.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Rob Lao's suggestion:

Put `$(this).popover("dispose");` before each of the `$(this).popover` and remove all the `$(this).click(function() {       $(this).popover("hide");     });`

This gives:

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", calc);

function calc() {
  let a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);
  let b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b").value);
  let c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c").value);
  let output = document.getElementById("output");
  
  if (a === 0) {
    $(this).popover("dispose");
    $(this).popover({
      placement: "bottom",
      content: '<textarea class="popover-textarea"></textarea>',
      template:
        '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div>' +
        '<div class="row"><div class="col-3 my-auto">' +
        '</div><div class="popover-content col-9">You have chosen 0, this needs to be non-zero' +
        "</div></div>",
    });
    $(this).popover("show");

    return false;
  } else if (b === c) {
    $(this).popover("dispose");
    $(this).popover({
      placement: "bottom",
      content: '<textarea class="popover-textarea"></textarea>',
      template:
        '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div>' +
        '<div class="row"><div class="col-3 my-auto">' +
        '</div><div class="popover-content col-9">You have chosen b and c to be the same, they need to be different' +
        "</div></div>",
    });
    $(this).popover("show");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
<input type="number" id="a">
  <input type="number" id="b">
    <input type="number" id="c">
  <button type="button" id="submit">Hit me</button>
  </form>
  <p id="output"></p>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code still has multiple problems, e.g., the templates are used incorrectly. Yet, the underlying problem is that dynamic popovers are not a good design choice..  For better alternatives see Bootstrap 4 [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) and Bootstrap 5 built-in [form validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/)

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to get all the components of Bootstrap 5 working, especially Navbars - I tried lots of alternatives and I couldn't get it to work. I am going to focus on updating that first then I will look at this validation. I need to be able to express != 0 though, and I am not sure if that is possible in HTML.